# Track small differences in 5 files with Mercurial?

Tags: python, apache, mercurial, dvcs

I have five httpd.conf files which differ only in the port number that they are listening on. All of the other data between the sites is the same. Is there any way to track this as a single file in Mercurial? So that if I make a different change to the httpd.conf file, I could push this to all five, and keep the port numbers separate.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using the [include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include) directive in your httpd.conf files. Then you can keep each of the 5 very small and keep all the common stuff in a separate file.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the Include directive for the single part that differs? It's just a dumb, lexical "put that file here" kinda deal so should be idea for your needs.

Also, you could do this:

```
Listen ${LISTEN}
```

in your config file and pass that value in as an env var.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can; that's not a common thing to do in a VCS.  If I'm wrong, I'm happy to be corrected.

Perhaps you can make the "master" httpd.conf file a template, and have a build script that generates the five files you want, passing in the appropriate port number for each file.  That way you isolate the change points in your file, and keep the common bits, well, common.  There are reams of templateing languages out there.  Or you can simply use `sed`.  Or do as nmichaels suggested and use Apache's capabilities directly.

There are lots of ways to skin this particular cat, but I don't think Mercurial is going to help you directly.